# how to print all the possible combination of a set of bracket and expession so that they can be evaluated later?

Tags: java, substring, brackets

Below is a code snippet where brack is a set of brackets which are balanced and myExpression contains a logical operation may be having a | and & operator. Is there any way by which I can print all possible combination of bracket.

```
 /*  //  myExpression=a|b|c&d brack=((()))    */


brack = brack.substring(0,1) + brack.substring(1,2) + brack.substring(2,3) + 
  myExpression.substring(0,3) + brack.substring(3,4) + 
  myExpression.substring(3,5) + brack.substring(4,5) + 
  myExpression.substring(5,7) + brack.substring(5,6);
```

This is a manual approach I have tried.
These should print `(((a|b)|c)&d), (a|(b|(c&d))), ((a|b)|(c&d)), (a|((b|c)&d)), ((a|(b|c))&d)` and as soon as we increase the brackets and expression length then it should show all the possible combination of bracket and variables.

Comment: So what is your question ?

Comment: wnat to write in code so that it would automatically print all the possible combination of a set of bracket and expession so that they can be evaluated later is my question @soufrk

Answer (score -1):

clarify me whether your output seems to be wrong , as  `myExpression=a|b|c&d`
so when wrapping up this with brackets, the valid one will be as,

```
((a|b)|(c&d))
```

but what your example showing is

```
(((a|b)|c)|d)
```

which is wrong as you dont have `&` in it.

Comment: thanks @ideano1 for pointing my mistake out. But yes I have a certain set of bracket as input and a certain set of expression as input too. So I want to combine both of them and produce some valid expresssions so that I can extract values later . The brackets cannot be like (((a)))|b|c&d. It needs to be valid expresion.\

Comment: [link] https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-combinations-of-balanced-parentheses/ 
this link will give you the valid paranthesis..

and we need to evaluate for valid expressions